# In iOS UINavigationController, in each of screen transition rapidly consuming memory

Tags: ios, memory, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

I am developing iOS App.

In NavigationController, MainViewController has custom ContainerViewController(*YSLContainerViewController) which is composed of several UIViewController like the following code.

*YSLContainerViewController：https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLContainerViewController

```
MainViewController.m

@property (nonatomic) YSLContainerViewController *containerVC;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CategoryViewController *categoryViewController[5];

    categoryViewController[0] = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EachCategoryView"];
    categoryViewController[0].category = 0;
    categoryViewController[0].title = @"apple";

    categoryViewController[1] = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EachCategoryView"];
    categoryViewController[1].category = 1;
    categoryViewController[1].title = @"orange";

    categoryViewController[2] = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EachCategoryView"];
    categoryViewController[2].category = 2;
    categoryViewController[2].title = @"strawberry";

    categoryViewController[3] = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EachCategoryView"];
    categoryViewController[3].category = 3;
    categoryViewController[3].title = @"cherry";

    categoryViewController[4] = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EachCategoryView"];
    categoryViewController[4].category = 4;
    categoryViewController[4].title = @"watermelon";


     NSMutableArray *tabArray =
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:categoryViewController[0], categoryViewController[1], categoryViewController[2], categoryViewController[3], categoryViewController[4], nil];

    float navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

    _containerVC = [[YSLContainerViewController alloc]initWithControllers:tabArray
                                                                           topBarHeight:navigationbarHeight
                                                                            parentViewController:self];
    _containerVC.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_containerVC.view];

}
```

Each categoryViewController has TableView. When a cell in TableView is tapped, goes to detailViewController.

```
CategoryViewController.m
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Each time I repeat the above transition like

"(tap tableViewCell in) categoryViewController in MainViewController → detailViewController  → (go back to) MainViewController → (tap tableViewCell in) categoryViewController in MainViewController →　detailViewController → (go back to) MainViewController..."

,my app are rapidly consuming the memory , it will not be reduced.

I guess in each of transition categoryViewControllers are not released from memory.

I tried the following method, but it does not work well.

```
DetailViewController.m
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    ([self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];)
}
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are most likely keeping a strong reference to something which should've been a weak reference. Make sure all your delegates are weak,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In MainActivity.m, I set categoryViewController and cantainerVC to weak, however it does not work well.